# Api class that can Initialize dynamic modules and unite them under its hood

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out a pattern where a single class can instantiate dynamic module classes and attach them to itself.

For example, I have

Module 1

```
class object1 {
  construct(params) {
    this.params = params
  }
}

module.exports = object1
```

Module 2

```
class object2 {
  construct(params) {
    this.params = params
  }
}
module.exports = object2
```

And an API module that would somehow instantiate an unlimited amount of objects and sort of attach them to itself.

```
class Api {

}

module.exports = new Api;
```

The functionality of API module should work like so `let obj = api.object1('param1').object2('param2')` // `{ object1: {params: 'param1'}, object2: {params: 'param2'}}`

I can manually set all methods in the api class but that's not the solution I look for. I want to be able to initialize all modules and dynamically attach them onto the api class, pass all the arguments to modules and generate object in the output that sort of reflects the example above.

Is it achievable at all? Or maybe someone recognizes this pattern and know whats it called so that I could research it further? I tried achieving this using Proxy but was unsuccessful.